# Instrument with iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, ios9.3

I have upload my phone to 9.3.1. And now I have problem, I can't user Instrument tool with my phone. I already update my xcode to 7.3.1

Anyone here face this problem. Can help me?

Comment: Beside Instruments, can you run your app with it? Do you have the latest version of Xcode (7.3.1) installed?

Comment: Yes, I can build it normal. Just Instrument my phone is grey out and I can't do with it.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode and/or your computer ? (after closing Xcode)

Comment: I have try it. Also restart my device. But when I use command + i. It return unknow occur.

Comment: It should work, look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878283/unable-to-profile-app-on-device-with-ios-9-0-1-using-xcode-7-7-0-1-or-7-1-beta

Comment: @LA I already mark it duplicate with your link. We can follow step in this answers. Everything will be ok.