# Xcode Profile and physical device offline issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I would like to test my app on physical device using Xcode Profile tools but from some reason each device which I connect is marked as offline in Profiler.

[image]

What is the approach for making them as accessible to select?

I have:
Xcode 8.1

Comment: you can restart your device!  then connect your device  to your mac->open Xcode->press command + i
you could d this

Comment: or visite 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878283/unable-to-profile-app-on-device-with-ios-9-0-1-using-xcode-7-7-0-1-or-7-1-beta

Answer (score 3):

The first comment is right: after I restarted the device (and only the device, no re-connection was needed, even XCode shouldn't have been restarted), it worked.

Comment: That was it for my case. Weird though.